# HTTPServletRequest attributes lost after Guice injection

Tags: java, rest, servlets, https, guice

I use `Guice-Servlet` extension with `Jersey REST`. In my `ServletModule` I have registered a `Filter`. This filter reads some data from the input request JSON & set it to the `HttpServletRequest` as an attribute.

This request is then injected in some class, wherein the attribute is read from the request & used for further injections.

**The issue is**:
When I use a **HTTP** (http://localhost:8080), the attributes are there in the injected request.
But when I use **HTTPS** (https://localhost:8443), the attribute map in the injected request is empty.

Maybe the Guice-servlet extension does not handle HTTPS. I am stuck up with this issue. Please help & guide me.

Comment: Shouldn't have any difference. Please post your filter code. Also, are you sure there is no redirect working there?